# почему стейт отображает предыдущее значение

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hook

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

при нажатии на карту вызывается событие онклик, которое в функции меняет состояние divActive c помощью  setDivActive, вывожу в консоль это значение, при первом нажатии выводит значение предыдущей карты, если никакая карта выбрана не была, возвращает и вовсе пустую строку. Была активна первая карта, нажимаю на третью - в консоли 1, нажимаю с третьей на вторую - в консоли 3, при этом если на уже активную карту нажму второй раз, выводит верное значение. как передавать текущее значение, а не предыдущее?

```
const CardPrice = (props) => {
    return(
    <div className='price-div'>
        <h2>{props.name}</h2>
        <h1>{props.cost}</h1>
    </div>)
    }
    const PurchaseButton = () => {
    return (
        <div className='button-div'>
            <div className='bgCLip'>
            <button className='button-buy' >buy now</button>
            </div>
        </div>)
     }

    const Card = () => {
      const [divActive, setDivActive] = React.useState("");
    
      const changeClass = (el) => {
        setDivActive(el.target.id); 
        console.log(divActive);
     if(divActive === '1'){
      second.style='left:20%'
    }else if(divActive === '3'){
      second.style='left:59.4%'
    }
      }
            
      return(
        <div className='general-div'>
          <div 
            className={`price-card first ${divActive === '1' ? 'price-card__active' : "" } `}
            id='1' 
            onClick={changeClass}
          >
            <CardPrice name={'eco'} cost={'﹩14.99'} />
            <PurchaseButton />
          </div>

      <div 
        className={`price-card second ${divActive === '2' ? 'price-card__active' : "" } `}
        id='2' 
        onClick={changeClass}
      >
        <CardPrice name={'next'} cost={'﹩19.99'} />
        <PurchaseButton />
      </div>

      <div 
        className={`price-card third ${divActive === '3' ? 'price- 
  card__active' : "" } `}
        id='3' 
        onClick={changeClass}
      >
        <CardPrice name={'business'} cost={'﹩24.99'} />
        <PurchaseButton />
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}

    const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));
    root.render(
      <Card />
      );
```

```css
.general-div{
            width: 100vw;
            height: 100vh;
        }
        
        .price-card{
            width: 250px;
            height: 350px;
            background-image: linear-gradient(white ,rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.806));
            box-shadow: 0 0 30px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.35);
            transition: 0.3s;
            border-radius: 8px;
            margin: 10px;
            transition: 0.5s;
        }
        
        .price-card__active {
            background-image: linear-gradient(-235deg, rgba(151, 154, 196, 0.767) 5%, rgba(46, 20, 152, 0.807));
            border-radius: 12px;
            transition: 0.5s;
            transform:scale(1.04);
            scale: 1.02;
            color: white;
        }
        
        .price-card:hover{
            transition: 0.5s;
            scale: 1.01;
        }
        
        .first{
            position: absolute;
            top: 50%;
            left: 30%;
            transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
        }
        
        .second{
            position: absolute;
            top: 50%;
            left: 50%;
            transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
        }
        
        .third{
            position: absolute;
            top: 50%;
            left: 70%;
            transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
        }
        
        .price-card__active button {
            transition: 0.5s;
            color: black;
            background-image: linear-gradient(-235deg, rgb(151, 154, 196) 5%, rgb(46, 20, 152));
            -webkit-background-clip: text;
            -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
        }
    
    .button-div{
        width: 200px;
        height: 35px;
        position: absolute;
        bottom: 5%;
        left: 50%;
        transform: translate(-50%);
    }
    
    .button-buy {
        font-family: sans-serif;
        font-size: 25px;
        font-weight: bold;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        border-radius: 5px;
        background-image: linear-gradient(-235deg, rgba(151, 154, 196, 0.767) 5%, rgba(46, 20, 152, 0.807));
        border: none;
        cursor: pointer;
        color: #f3f3f3;
    }
    
    .bgCLip{
        width: 200px;
        height: 35px;
        position: absolute;
        bottom: 5%;
        left: 50%;
        transform: translate(-50%);
        background-image: linear-gradient(-235deg, rgba(246, 246, 246, 
       0.767) 5%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.807));
        border-radius: 5px;
    }
     
    
    .price-div{
        font-family: sans-serif;
       position: absolute;
       width: 100%;
       height: 100px;
       display: flex;
       justify-content: center;
       align-items: center;
       flex-direction: column;
    }
    
    .price-div h2{
        margin-top: 75px;
        margin-bottom: 10px;
        font-size: 20px;
    }
    
    .price-div h1{
        margin-top: 10px;
        font-size: 50px;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Покажите ваш код. Как минимум, из вопроса - все сеттеры состояния в реакте работают асинхронно и если вы консолите значение сразу после сеттера, то вы как раз видите предыдущее состояние.

Comment: Внутри функции **changeClass** обращайтесь не к **divActive**, а к **el.target.id** или, если изменения надо производить строго после смены состояния, то создайте useEffect с зависимостью divActive

Comment: спасибо, помогло